# write and read on real time pytables

Tags: python, real-time, pytables

I am not sure if what I am thinking would be possible, I would need the help from someone experienced working with HDF5/PyTables.

The escenario would be like this:

Let's say that we have a process, or a machine or a connexion etc, acquiring data, and storing in a HDF5/PyTable format. I will call it store software.

Would it be possible to have another software, I will call it analysis software, running on time?.

If it helps, the store software and the analysis software would be totally independent, even wrote on different languages.

My doubt is that, if the store program is writing the PyTable, `mode='w'`, then, at the same time, can the analysis program access in `mode='r'`, and read some data to perform some basic analysis, averages, etc, etc??.

The basic idea of this is to be able to analyze data stored in a PyTable on real time.

Of course any other proposed solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's **not recommended nor supported** to write in one process and read in others. Take a look at this question from [HDF 5 FAQ](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf5-quest.html):

> Does HDF5 support concurrent access to a single dataset from multiple processes?
>
> If all processes are reading, then, yes, HDF5 (serial) does support this. If there are any  processes that are writing, then no, this is not supported. We are working on a "Single Write Multiple Read" (SWMR) feature, which will be available in a future release (expected to be in HDF5-1.10).

Pytables doesn't guarantee this schema of write/reads as stated by @SmCaterpillar.

Answer (score -2):

This is definitely possible.  It is especially easy if you only have one process in 'w' and multiple processes in 'r' mode. Just make sure in your 'w' process to `flush()` the file and/or the datasets occasionally.  If you do this, the 'r' process will be able to see the data.

Comment: You sure this is a good idea? Quoting PyTables FAQ:

"Can PyTables be used in concurrent access scenarios?

Concurrent reads are no problem at all. However, whenever a process (or thread) is trying to write, then problems will start to appear. First, PyTables doesn't support locking at any level, so several process writing concurrently to the same PyTables file will probably end corrupting it, so don't do this! Even having only one process writing and the others reading is a hairy thing, because the reading processes might be reading incomplete data from a concurrent data writing operation."

Comment: Writes are locked in HDF5, as I recall, which is why this is OK.